# WPF | Datagrid - stop autocomplete date column

Tags: c#, binding, datagrid

I have a Datagrid which is bound to a Viewmodel.
if I enter a date in a cell, something interrupts the user and messes up the input.

For example:

If I enter the DataGridTextColumn cell in a new empty Row it starts with 01.01.0001 (german date layout)

If I replace the string and start typing the first number and dot into the field it works as expected. But the next typed number will generate a whole date with setting the active year as the default value.

So I type 01.4 and then the Input in the cell will change to 01.04.2019, this is quite annoying and I have no clue how to change the behaviour. But I need to, because this makes inserting many rows with dates not ranging in the current year very unintuitive

The binding is an ObservableCollection with a custom class that has the OnPropertyChanged Technique implemented.

please help me find the correct place to change this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the observed behaviour is only with a DateTime bound to a datagridtextcolumn. there is no simple or intuitive solution to change this behaviour.
My solution was to use a DataGridTemplateColumn, this control does not autocomplete your input in the most ridiculous und useless way imaginable.

Old Xaml:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Datum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=d}" Header="Aktionsdatum" />
```

New Xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pick a Date">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Datum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Datum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added: "StringFormat=d" to the first Binding in order to get a correct formating.